# AWK text file comparison (how many times contains 'b' file the strings from 'a' file)

Tags: string, bash, awk

I have a smaller txt, around 50.000 lines, (a.txt) and a bigger txt file, around 1m lines, (b.txt)

I would like to know how many times do b.txt contains the strings from a.txt

```
(if [[ $s1 == *"$s2"* ]]).
```

Facts:
Each lines length is between 5-65 characters
Every line contains only one string
English letters only
There is no spaces in the strings
There wont be exact match

Here is my source code. It is working, but it is pretty slow. 
Can you please help me how can I do it faster?

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} {s=$1; for (i in a) if (index(i, $1)) s=s FS i; if (s!=$1) print  s}' a.txt b.txt > result.txt
```

The ideal output would be in results.txt:

Example:

**a1string** is the first string in *a.txt*, if *b.txt* contains more than once **a1string** then in i write **a1string**, and the strings from *b.txt* that contains **a1string**

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to make this radically faster.  One thing which might help would be to print each match as a line with the search string and the matching line, then sort and summarize, but it might even be slower, just less awkward to handle than your current output format.

Comment: Maybe the search strings file could be converted into a `flex` source file and compiled, but I suspect that would still not make it a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -F -c -f a.txt b.txt
```

`-F` says to perform exact matching, rather than regular expressions. `-c` means to count the matching lines, rather than printing them. `-f a.txt` means to take the strings to match from the file `a.txt`, rather than from command line arguments.

To see all the individual matches, use the `-o` option. Then pipe it to `sort` and `uniq` to get the counts of each.

```
grep -F -o -f a.txt b.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Comment: Hello, there wont be any exact match

Comment: The exact match can be anywhere on the line, it's not matching the whole line (that's what the `-x` option does).

Comment: OK, now I can see that there are 14000 matches. How can I which strings from a.txt was found in b.txt (and how many times)?

Comment: Hi, can I sort the output? (desc)

Comment: Of course you can. That's the beauty of pipelines. See the update

Comment: Can you please check my other pipeline question?